# how can i set the datetime-local input so i can choose a datetime from the current date and onwards

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, datetimepicker, datetime-local

i want to have an input feild where i can choose date and time in the future from the current date
i tried lot of solutions but when i try to choose a datetime it's giving me to choose between a time range witch i don't want ,i want to choose the date i want myself
here is the message i get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSekj.jpg)

does anyone have a solution for this in laravel
i'm trying to set an expiration date for my records

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (and if you *really* need an image of something, learn how to take a screenshot, rather than a wonky photo). Instead, show us a [mre] - a small sample of code, a description of what you hoped it would do, and an exact description of what it did instead.

Comment: The error message makes it look like you specified a "step" of one minute, that this will be allowed to increase or decrease by, and the initial value probably had the seconds set to `57` ...? We really can't tell what is actually going on here, based on nothing but your frontend screenshot.

Comment: Try to make your problem clearer, include the code, tell us what's the problem in details

Comment: here is the code for my form : <input type="datetime-local" id="e_expire" name="expire" min="{{ date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') }}" value="{{ old('expire') }}" class="form-control @error('expire') is-invalid @enderror" required> ,and this line is from my controller : 'expire' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s',,i didn't mention any step!!